# configure: error: xml2-config not found. Please check your libxml2 installation

Tags: php, fedora

I am trying to install php5 to my fedora 14. But when I ./configure the error shows `configure: error: xml2-config not found. Please check your libxml2 installation.`. I installed libxml2 and when I run `yum install libxml2` it says `Package libxml2-2.7.7-3.fc14.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`
. What is happening

Answer (score 0):

You should install devel package.

Comment: I also run `yum install libxml2-dev` and it says `No package libxml2-dev available.
Error: Nothing to do
`!!

Comment: Can you post the output of yum search libxml2 ? Does yum install libxml2-devel works better?

Comment: It's `libxml2-devel`. Also if you are unsure about a name again search for it: `yum search libxml2`

Comment: Thanks faker. It was `libxml2-devel`.